# When obscuring a class with an interface, do overridden implementations remain?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the `IWebElement` interface . It requires the `Click()` method to be implemented. Some methods in WebDriver library return implemented `IWebElement` as a result.

I have my own interface `IPageElement: IWebElement` and a concrete class `PageElement` that implements `Click();` method differently (some waits and exception handling).

Say I have 2 methods:

```
IPageElement GetSomething() => new PageElement();
IWebElement GetSomethingElse() => new PageElement();
```

As far as I know, results will be cut to retain only the interface members. But would I keep the overridden `Click();` implementation from `PageElement` in both cases?

Comment: What happened when you tried running click method on whatever returned from `GetSomething` and `GetSomethingElse`?

Comment: An interface does not have an implementation so non of the implementations in PageElement will 'override' any existing logic

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, It would probably click on it somehow. Since checking implementation requires an Exception and I don't exactly have console easily available in a test project to attach a `Console.WriteLine` it's not that simple to test which implementation is actually used.

Comment: You *do* have a browser so you could try it here [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/). Create some classes and an interface and see what happens. It will take less effort than posting the original question on [so].

Comment: Try what is suggested by Igor. It should clear your doubts. Even after that you have any confusion feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write some code.

```
interface IW
{
  void C();
}
interface IP : IW
{
  void D();
}
class W : IW
{
  public virtual void C() { Console.WriteLine("WC"); }
}
class P : W, IP
{
  public override void C() { Console.WriteLine("PC"); }
  public virtual void D() { Console.WriteLine("PD"); }
}
...
IP ip = new P();
ip.C(); // PC
IW iw = new P();
ip.C(); // PC
```

In both cases, the overriding implementation wins.

However, **it is very important that it is an overriding implementation**.  There is a very subtle and often misunderstood rule in C#.  Consider this case:

```
class W2 : IW
{
  public void C() { Console.WriteLine("W2C"); } // NOT VIRTUAL
}
class P2 : W2, IP
{
  public new void C() { Console.WriteLine("P2C"); }
  public virtual void D() { Console.WriteLine("P2D"); }
}
```

What happens here?

```
IP ip = new P2();
ip.C();
IW iw = new P2();
ip.C();
```

Again, we get P2C both times.  So everything seems fine, even if the "override" is a non virtualized overload, right?

So what happens when we do this?

```
class P3 : P2
{
  public new void C() { Console.WriteLine("P3C"); }
}
...
IP ip = new P3();
ip.C();
IW iw = new P3();
ip.C();
```

**We still get P2C both times**. This may be surprising!  The non-virtual overriding overloaded method does NOT update the interface implementation here, but it did in the previous example!  Why is that?

If you do this:

```
class P4 : P2, IP // NOTE IP
{
  public new void C() { Console.WriteLine("P4C"); }
}
...
IP ip = new P4();
ip.C();
IW iw = new P4();
ip.C();
```

Then we **do** get P4C printed out.

The rule in C# is that the compiler decides which method slot is associated with which interface member **when the interface is mentioned in the inheritance list**.  That's the only germane difference between P3 and P4.

This is called the "interface re-implementation rule" in C# and it is quite tricky.  Be *very careful* if you are going to mix non-virtual methods with interface re-implementation and inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any implementation of IPageElement must implement both the Click() and the GetSomething() methods so those methods will both be available on any resulting implementation of IPageElement. If that same implementation is assigned to IWebElement, only the click method will be available since GetSomething is not defined by IWebElement.

```
public interface IWebElement
{
    void Click();
}

public interface IPageElement : IWebElement
{
    void GetSomething();
}

public class PageElementImpl : IPageElement
{
    public void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click");
    }

    public void GetSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetSomething");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebElement webElement = new PageElementImpl();
    IPageElement pageElement = new PageElementImpl();

    webElement.Click();  //Legal
    pageElement.Click();  //Legal
    webElement.GetSomething();  //Not Legal as GetSomething() is not part of IWebElment
    pageElement.GetSomething();  //Legal
}
```